# Printing output of a python script with html/css/php

Tags: php, python, html

I would like to run a script in python with a button on a web page. I already write my script in python and the design of the web page. 
My python last a few minutes and I have to print on the page the output of the script. But when I press the button, the script start and the page stay in loading and all the text appears at the end... So I would like to print the output in real time.

By the way, I'm sorry for my English but I'm Belgian ^^

Thanks.

Kevin.

Comment: Have you looked at [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)?

Comment: No, I haven't because I didn't know this library but I will check that tomorrow morning